Why am I getting a TypeError when adding console.log to my code
I have the following code that works fine:


const user = {
    hello() {
        console.log("Hi:", this)
    }
}

const commonJs = (user) => function() {
    (0, user["hello"])()
}

commonJs(user)()



However, when I add console.log("Running"), I get the error Uncaught TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function:


const user = {
    hello() {
        console.log("Hi:", this)
    }
}

const commonJs = (user) => function() {
    console.log("Running")
    (0, user["hello"])()
}

commonJs(user)()



I don't understand why this happens since I thought adding a simple console.log would not cause any issues.
I noticed that when I add a semicolon (;) after console.log("Running"), the error disappears:


const user = {
    hello() {
        console.log("Hi:", this)
    }
}

const commonJs = (user) => function() {
    console.log("Running");
    (0, user["hello"])()
}

commonJs(user)()



But I don't understand why the error occurs without the semicolon.

It you're going to write JS without semicolons, you must know the ASI rules.

Without the semicolon, the code is getting interpreted as this:
console.log("Running")(0, user["hello"])()

Since .log() doesn't return anything, the type error happens because it looks like you are trying to call a function that .log() returns.
